# How can I burn an ISO onto an external hard drive's partition?

Tags: linux, iso-image, burning

I want to install a Linux ISO to an external hard drive, but I don't have an extra USB so I wanted to make a smaller 8gb partition off of the external hard drive and then temporarily burn the ISO content there. Then after I finish installing the OS, I'll just merge it back into the overall size.

I can wipe the entire external hard drive, I want to dedicate it to Linux. However, I'm using Windows 10 as my host OS right now. I placed the temporary partition at the end because I figured putting it as the first would cause issues once I want to merge it back later.

Comment: Specifying the exact image you want to use (or at least a distro) will allow fellow users to experiment in order to help you.

Comment: Well I was meaning to install MX Linux

Comment: One approach is to use virtualization to boot the image. E.g. in VirtualBox you can boot directly from an image and pass USB through, so the installer "sees" your external hard drive "directly". The problem may arise because your non-virtual hardware is different. Some distros can install popular drivers even if they are not needed at the moment, so the OS (usually) can boot later on different hardware if only the architecture fits. If MX chooses to save space by installing necessary components only, then it may not boot on your physical hardware after being installed this way.

Comment: Burning is in reference to CD/DVD optical discs, you don't burn anything to a hard drive.

Comment: What is the term I should use then? I used "burning" because that's a word that can clearly make my point clear as to what I wanted to do @Moab

Comment: You would extract/copy the contents of the ISO to that partition.

Comment: Is that really all it takes when you "burn" it to a regular USB? If so, I'll give it a shot later

Comment: Did it work? Feel free to add an answer here...